# WebBrowser link JavaScript file from Project Resources

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have **index.html** and **script.js** in my project resources. And in html file, I try to link script **script.js** with it:

`<script src="script.js"></script>`

Also I have **Form** which have a **WebBrowser** control and its url is **index.html**. And no problem here.

The problem is when I test the application and run **WebBrowser**, it give me a script error which it's mean there's no file name **script.js**, and cannot link with it.

What I should type here instead of `????` ??

`<script src="????/script.js"></script>`

Here's the error:
[image: Script error]

Comment: You need to include the js file into the output directory.

Comment: That exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is based on that comment, but if you're trying to hide your js code from the user, you can't. Also, based on the question alone, it sounds like you need the exact same path as before: `src="script.js"` When you init the WebBrowser, what URL are you supplying?

Comment: I don't want to hide, Just I don't want to copy **script.js** file to output directory

Comment: So include it in the html file.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it works fine, I was wondering if there's better way.

Comment: What do you mean by a better way? Better with what benefits?

Comment: As another option you can copy both files to a temp directory at runtiem and load them from the temp path.

Comment: Without let my html code hard to read, a lot of lines.

Comment: I don't want to actually write up an answer for this, but another way is to simply read your JS file into memory as a string, then get a script tag by tagname  then effectively do a += on the the InnerText property and append your JS file as as string.

Comment: It's a nice way to do it also, please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of following options:

- Include the js file content in the same html file.
- Copy both html and js file into the same directory at run-time, for example a temp directory.

**Example**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    var indexPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "index.html");
    var scriptPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "script.js");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(indexPath, Properties.Resources.index);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(scriptPath, Properties.Resources.script);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(indexPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since you requested it, the basic idea is to read your JS file into a string, then create a script tag element and then insert it on the body. Also remember to set the JS file to `Copy to Output Directory` from the properties window if you are using visual studio.

You have a JS file that looks like this:

```
alert("Include me");
```

You have CS file that looks like this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.html");
            var page = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
            webBrowser1.Navigate(path);
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        }
        private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newScript = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
            webBrowser1.Document.Body.InsertAdjacentElement(HtmlElementInsertionOrientation.AfterEnd, newScript);
            var path =Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.js");
            var script =File.ReadAllText(path);
            newScript.InnerText = script;
        }
    }
}
```

I used an HTML file that looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

          <h1>Test Text</h1>
        </div><!-- content container -->

        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I did this, I ended up with a result that looks like this:
 [image]